# using $(this) to find the forms submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

doing some validation and using jQuery Q-Tip to show errors.

I have multiples of the same forms on the same page and only want the error tip to show underneath the current forms submit button.

This is the structure:

```
<form action='process/reportcomment.php' method='post' class='reportcommentform' name='reportcommentform'>
    <input type='hidden' value='' name='commentID'>
    <input type='hidden' value='' name='comment'>
    <input class='reportcommentsubmit' name='submit-report' type='submit' value='report'> 
</form>
```

And then i need to find the submit-report button with jQuery.

I have tried this in my ajax response:

```
    if (response.cantReport === true) {
        errorMessage = 'Please wait 30 mins';
        errorField = $(this).find('.reportcommentsubmit');
        showErrorMessage(errorMessage, errorField);
    }
```

But to no luck.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the `this` element in your code?

Comment: $('.reportcommentsubmit') will be your button. You don't need to find it

Comment: Where did you *try* that code? When does it get executed? `onSubmit`?

Comment: @Pavlo OP will need to find it as the question states that the HTML structure in the example is duplicated multiple times.

Comment: @mrrogers have edited my post to show how i am using it in my ajax response

Comment: you need to set context option to ajax request

Comment: Still not quite enough context.  in Javascript `this` is defined based on the way the function get's called.  If `this` that you're trying to access is nested within an Ajax call, is probably not `this` that you are expecting.  Can you give that JS snippet some more context?  is it the error callback?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
errorField = $(this).closest('form').find('.reportcommentsubmit');
```

Otherwise, you have wrapping code around the `$(this)`, which makes it not the same `this` as the button's, but the one in your wrapping jQuery call. When you get in such a situation you need to store the parent `this` like so;

```
var _this = this;

$.POST('address', {}, function(data) {
    console.log(_this); // using $(this) here won't be the button's $(this) here because there's a lambda function claiming the scope
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct if I'm wrong, but what I understood here is that you want to get the form from which a submit button has been clicked?

Then I would do the following:

```
$('.reportcommentsubmit').bind('click', handleSubmit);
...
function handleSubmit(e) {
    var form = $(e.target).closest('form');
    // do something with my form ...
    // or : 
    $(e.target).after('<div>Wait Wait wait ... Are you sure everything is correct?</div>')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All form controls in a form have a *form* property that is a reference to the form. So if *this* is any control in the form and the submit button has a name and you know what it is, you can do:

```
var submitButton = this.form.submitButtonName;
```

Otherwise, you can loop over the *form.elements* collection to find the submit button by type:

```
var controls = this.form.elements;
for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if (controls[i].type == 'submit') {
    // controls[i] is a submit button
  }
}
```